# Flutter User Filter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  List<User> allusers = [];
  List<User> selectedUsers = [];
  List<User> selectableUsers = allusers - selectedUsers
```

Is anyone able to help me how to get selectableUsers list here? I am trying to subtract the selected users from all users so that the search function eliminates selectedUsers?

I want to filter users based on the selection.

View for getting and searching users. Issue is that selected user gets into the search once again. Expected behavior is that "selected" users shouldn't come up in the "selectable" user list.

```
class SearchGroup extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchGroup({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SearchGroup> createState() => _SearchGroupState();
}

class _SearchGroupState extends State<SearchGroup> {
  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();

  List<User> _users = [];
  List<User> _selectedUsers = [];
  List<User> _selectableUsers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var setAllUsers = Set.from(_users);
    var setSelectedUsers = Set.from(_selectedUsers);
    _selectableUsers
        .addAll(List.from(setAllUsers.difference(setSelectedUsers)));
  }

  _clearSearch() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => _searchController.clear());
    setState(() => _selectableUsers = []);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _searchController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentUserUid =
        Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser?.uid ?? '';
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: TextField(
            controller: _searchController,
              hintText: 'Search & select users by fullname',
              suffixIcon: _selectableUsers.isEmpty
                  ? Icon(Icons.search,
                      size: 20.0, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 228, 228))
                  : IconButton(
                      iconSize: 15,
                      icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.clear_circled_solid),
                      onPressed: _clearSearch,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 228, 228)),
            ),
            onSubmitted: (input) async {
              if (input.trim().isNotEmpty) {
                List<User> users =
                    await Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context, listen: false)
                        .searchUsers(currentUserUid, input);

                _selectedUsers.forEach((user) => users.remove(user));
                _selectableUsers.forEach((user) => users.remove(user));

                setState(() {
                  _selectableUsers = users;
                });
              }
            }),
    
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 100,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _selectedUsers.length,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    User selectedUser = _selectedUsers[index];
                    return Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          _selectedUsers.remove(selectedUser);
                          _selectableUsers.insert(0, selectedUser);
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        child: Stack(
                          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomEnd,
                          children: [
                            CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 60,
                              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                imageUrl: selectedUser.profileImageUrl,
                                imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) =>
                                    Container(
                                  height: 60,
                                  width: 60,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                      image: imageProvider,
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              top: 3,
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.remove_circle,
                                size: 20,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return const Divider(thickness: 1.0);
              },
              itemCount: _selectedUsers.length + _selectableUsers.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                if (index < _selectedUsers.length) {
                  User selectedUser = _selectedUsers[index];
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 28,
                      child: CachedNetworkImage(
                        imageUrl: selectedUser.profileImageUrl,
                        imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      selectedUser.fullname,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                    ),
                    
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: blueColor),
                    onTap: () {
                      _selectedUsers.remove(selectedUser);
                      _selectableUsers.insert(0, selectedUser);
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  int userIndex = index - _selectedUsers.length;
                  User user = _selectableUsers[userIndex];

                  return ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 28,
                      child: CachedNetworkImage(
                        imageUrl: user.profileImageUrl,
                        imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      user.fullname,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                    ),
                    
                    trailing: Icon(
                      CupertinoIcons.circle,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      _selectedUsers.add(user);
                      _selectableUsers.remove(user);
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
onSubmitted: (input) async {
    if (input.trim().isNotEmpty) {
        List<User> users = await Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context, listen: false).searchUsers(currentUserUid, input);
        
        var setAllUsers = Set.from(users);
        var setSelectedUsers = Set.from(selectedUsers);
        
        setState(() {
            selectableUsers.addAll(List.from(setAllUsers.difference(setSelectedUsers)));
        });
    }
}),
```

You also need add [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package to your user model class, lets assume this is your model
class:

```
class User extends Equatable {// <-- add this
  final String fullName;
  final String avatar;
  final int phone;
  const User({
    required this.fullName,
    required this.avatar,
    required this.phone,
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [fullName, avatar, phone];// <-- add this
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am getting this error. The instance member 'allUsers' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression.

Comment: List<User> _users = [];
List<User> _selectedUsers = [];
List _selectableUsers = [];

var setAllUsers = Set.from(_users);
var setSelectedUsers = Set.from(_selectedUsers);
List selectableUsers = List.from(_users.difference(_selectedUsers));

Comment: I updated my answer again, check it out, @Eren

Comment: awesome! So final piece is that I have a search function but it doesn't pick the users when I use your suggestion. It does pick all users if use "all users"  onSubmitted: (input) async {
              if (input.trim().isNotEmpty) {
                List<User> users =
                    await Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context, listen: false)
                        .searchUsers(currentUserUid, input);
                setState(() {
                  _selectableUsers = users;
                });
              }
            }

Comment: I didn't understand of your last issue, could you update your question and and ask it clearly?

Comment: could you print("users = $users"); before call setState?

Comment: yes! Now I am actually getting the same behavior as all users. Let me play around with my listview builder if I am doing something wrong there...

Comment: So this answer did fix your issue?

Comment: No actually, I am not seeing the filter I was expecting on the search results. Do you know if we should use setstate in your function? Currently allusers behave same as selectableUsers. I can copy and paste the whole code if it's more helpful in the original description.

Comment: could you provide simple code snippet so I run and find you issue?

Comment: of course! @eamirho3ein. I added the code in the original section. Thanks in advance! Basically, first time a user searches, everything looks good but if the user searches the same user then that specific user re-appears in the search results and can be selected once again... Expected behavior is that "selectable" users shouldn't include "selected" users.

Comment: I am still seeing the same behavior on the additional searches. Do you reckon I have to update anything below "ListView.separated"?

Comment: I updated again, check it out.

Comment: super! Thanks again @eamirho3ein. I really appreciate it...

Answer (score 0):

A basic way of doing will be checking each item like

```dart
  List<User> allusers = [];
  List<User> selectedUsers = [];
  List<User> selectableUsers = [];
  for (final user in allusers) {
    if (!selectableUsers.contains(user)) selectableUsers.add(user);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this approach but it didn't work.